# import runs tests twice in pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

why does `py.test` run the `TestFoo.test_foo()` test there? I understand it runs `TestBar.test_foo()`.

Contents of `test_foo.py`:

```
import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        print "in test_foo"
```

Contents of `test_bar.py`:

```
from test_foo import TestFoo

class TestBar(TestFoo):
    def test_bar(self):
        print "in test_bar"
```

Output:

```
[999]anarcat@marcos:t$ pytest -v
no test dir found testing here: /tmp/t
===========================  test_bar.py  ============================
test_bar (test_bar.TestBar) ... in test_bar
ok
test_foo (test_bar.TestBar) ... in test_foo
ok
test_foo (test_foo.TestFoo) ... in test_foo
ok

===========================  test_foo.py  ============================
test_foo (test_foo.TestFoo) ... in test_foo
ok

*******************************************************************************
Ran 4 test cases in 0.00s (0.00s CPU)
All 2 modules OK
```

If `TestBar` is put in the same file as `TestFoo`, the `TestFoo.test_foo()` test get ran only once:

```
import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        print "in test_foo"

class TestBar(TestFoo):
    def test_bar(self):
        print "in test_bar"
```

Output:

```
[1001]anarcat@marcos:t$ pytest -v
no test dir found testing here: /tmp/t
===========================  test_foo.py  ============================
test_bar (test_foo.TestBar) ... in test_bar
ok
test_foo (test_foo.TestBar) ... in test_foo
ok
test_foo (test_foo.TestFoo) ... in test_foo
ok

*******************************************************************************
Ran 3 test cases in 0.00s (0.00s CPU)
All 1 modules OK
```

Shouldn't py.test ignore the tests that are found behind imports?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way to fix this is to import the module instead of importing the test class.

```
import test_foo

class TestBar(test_foo.TestFoo):
    def test_bar(self):
        print "in test_bar"
```

This will allow you to access the `TestFoo` class without having the tests run twice.

Answer (score 1):

No.  It doesn't have a good way to ignore imports.  Test runners simply enumerate the names defined in a module and execute ones that look like a test.  For example, if you import the first *test_bar.py* and `dir` the module, it defines both `TestFoo` and `TestBar`.  The test runner sees both tests and executes them.

Similarly, `TestBar` has two methods - `test_bar` and `test_foo`.  The test runner does not distinguish between names defined by the test class and those inherited from base classes.

Answer (score -1):

from test_foo import TestFoo :- this sentence will make TestFoo class available to test_bar.py

and

class TestBar(TestFoo): this makes TestBar Class extends TestFoo....

## Contents of test_bar.py

## this is because u are importing class

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        print ("in test_foo")

class TestBar(TestFoo):
    #this is because u are extending TestFoo and hence its function are also available to TestBar
    def test_foo(self):
        print ("in test_foo")

```
def test_bar(self):
    print ("in test_bar")
```

now its crystal clear what would be the output if u run this particular module..